# How is this a field?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

From Stephen Abbott's - understanding analysis there is a section in the text which says:

"The finite set  $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is a field when addition and multiplication are computed modulo 5."

I wasn't so familiar with the term "modulo" so quick googling yielded [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)
Is the idea that an addition or multiplication which in theory yields a number greater than 4, is supposed to "wrap around" the set and begin from zero again?

so $4+1 = 0 $ ?

Otherwise, I do not see how this satisfies the properties of a field, namely having an additive identity and multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Yes, $4+1 = 0,\, 3\cdot 3 = 4$ etc.

Comment: The additive identity is 0.

Comment: @wowlolbrommer Sorry - meant additive inverse, which I am thinking is satisfied when the set loops around itself after traversing 4, is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. 4 and 1 are each others' additive inverses (4+1=5=0 modulo 5), and 2 and 3 also (2+3=5=0 modulo 5).

Comment: Other things to prove: associative, commutative, distributive laws.

Comment: It turns out that the set of numbers $\{0,\dots,p-1\}$ with everything computed modulo $p$ is a field if and only if $p$ is prime. On the other hand, consider $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ (a notation for $\{0,\dots,5\}$ modulo $6$ — another common notation is $\Bbb Z_6$). This is not a field, because $2$ has no multiplicative inverse. (If it did, then we would have $3=(2^{-1}\cdot2)\cdot3=2^{-1}\cdot(2\cdot3)=2^{-1}\cdot0=0$. Remember that $2\cdot3=0$ modulo $6$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of modular arithmetic either as the numbers wrapping around, or what's more typical is to think of the numbers as remainders when divided by 5 (in this case).  You can write any integer $m$ as $m=5n+r$ then $m\equiv r \text{ mod } 5$.  0 is the additive identity.  1 is the multiplicative identity.  Both operations are commutative and associative.  To see that every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse you could just write out the multiplication table... The additive inverse is just the negative (as usual).  So $-2 = -1*5+3$ and hence $-2 \equiv 3\text{ mod }5$.  So the additive inverse of 2 is 3 (because $2+3=5\equiv 0$).

Answer (score 3):

Multiplicative inverses:
$$
1\cdot 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\\
2\cdot 3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\\
3\cdot 2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
\\
4\cdot 4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}
$$

Generally: addition mod $m$ is a field if and only if $m$ is prime.

Comment: This is because, modulo 5, the numbers 1, 6, and 16 are all the same.